# In Erlang's EUnit, assert that a function was called with an anonymous function

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching, eunit, meck

I have some code that looks like this:

```erl
-module(ca_data).
-export([delete_ca_data/1]).

% ...

delete_ca_data(N) when N < 1 -> ?NEGATIVE_ID_ERROR;
delete_ca_data(N) -> util_db_generic:delete_object(ca_data, N, fun(_) -> ok end).

% ...
```

And I have some test code that looks like this:

```erl
wrap_meck(MockMod, MockArgs, F) ->
    meck:new(MockMod, MockArgs),
    try
        F()
    catch Ex ->
        throw(Ex)
    after
        meck:unload(MockMod)
    end.

delete_ca_data_test() ->
    F = fun() ->
        meck:expect(util_db_generic, delete_object, fun (_, _, _) -> ok end),

        ?assertEqual(?NEGATIVE_ID_ERROR, ca_data:delete_ca_data(-1)),

        ?assertEqual([], meck:history(util_db_generic)),

        meck:expect(util_db_generic, delete_object, fun(_, _, _) -> ok end),
        ?assertEqual(ok, ca_data:delete_ca_data(1)),

        ?assertEqual(
            [{self(), {util_db_generic, delete_object, [ca_data, 1, fun(_) -> ok end]}, ok}], % Uh-oh
            meck:history(util_db_generic)
        )
    end,
    wrap_meck(util_db_generic, [], F).
```

Unfortunately, the `util_db_generic:delete_object` function is called with a function created in the module under test.

This provides some issues when trying to assert the history of the function calls (for example, on the line marked "Uh-oh"). Since this function is created in-situ (and the memory pointer is effectively random), it's challenging to assert what this function *should* look like. This code *does not* result in any compilation error. However, the asserts will never return as valid, since there are two different functions being asserted against each other (one created in the `ca_data` module, and one in the testcase). I tried using `?assertMatch` and changing the `fun(_) -> ok end`'s out for `_`s, but I am getting this compilation error on the assert line:

```
illegal pattern
```

How can I match these results?

Answer (score 3):

The assertion you want might look something like this:

```erl
?assertMatch(
    [{Self, {util_db_generic, delete_object, [ca_data, 1, Fun]}, ok}] when Self == self() andalso is_function(Fun, 1), % Yay?
    meck:history(util_db_generic)
)
```

This matches the `?assertMatch` documentation, in that you would write the same in a case statement like this:

```erl
case meck:history(util_db_generic) of
    [{Self, {util_db_generic, delete_object, [ca_data, 1, Fun]}, ok}] when Self == self() andalso is_function(Fun, 1) ->
        true;
    _ ->
        false
end
```

*(Note, the case statement could have been shorter with a `,` in-between the guards but that does not work in the macro so here we have to use `andalso` instead)*

The reason you have to match the pid to `Self` first and then check it in a guard is that no function calls are allowed in match expressions:

```erl
1> [self()] = [self()].
* 1:2: illegal pattern
```

Therefore, you have to bind it first and then check the value in a guard. If course, what you wrote above, binding `Self` outside of the expression also works. It is just a matter of taste and/or readability (in fact, I think binding `Self` first is clearer).

Answer (score 0):

While the Erlang documentation is usually good, this is one point where it lets the user down. [The `assertMatch` documentation states](https://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html#Assert_macros):

```
Evaluates Expr and matches the result against GuardedPattern, if testing is enabled. ... GuardedPattern can be anything that you can write on the left hand side of the -> symbol in a case-clause, except that it cannot contain comma-separated guard tests.
```

[And the documentation for `self()` states](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#self-0):

```
Allowed in guard tests.
```

However, the `self()` function cannot be used this the `assertMatch` macro. I am unclear on why, but experiment has proved this out.

---

EDIT 1:

The plot thickens! When I edit the test code to look like this:

```erl
delete_ca_data_test() ->
    F = fun() ->
        meck:expect(util_db_generic, delete_object, fun (_, _, _) -> ok end),

        ?assertEqual(?NEGATIVE_ID_ERROR, ca_data:delete_ca_data(-1)),

        ?assertEqual([], meck:history(util_db_generic)),

        meck:expect(util_db_generic, delete_object, fun(_, _, _) -> ok end),
        ?assertEqual(ok, ca_data:delete_ca_data(1)),

        Self = self(),

        ?assertEqual(
            [{Self, {util_db_generic, delete_object, [ca_data, 1, _]}, ok}], % Uh-oh
            meck:history(util_db_generic)
        )
    end,
    wrap_meck(util_db_generic, [], F).
```

the code compiles and runs correctly! This is, to me, a surprising result! The function (that should be able to be used in guards) is not allowed, but the return from the function is! Interesting!

Comment: The first part of `?assertEqual` is not a guard at all: https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/93b4c656bd0a80dbf67af4880ac186f5ae961ef8/lib/stdlib/include/assert.hrl#L226